# Как загрузить VirtualBox с USB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, usb, iso-образ

Пытаюсь создать виртуальную машину с ОС Windows 7 Ultimate архитектуры х64 в программе Oracle VM VirtualBox с помощью загрузочной USB 2.0 флешки. 
С самого начала при попытке выбрать это устройства вылезала ошибка, рассказывающая об отсутствии Extension Pack. Без проблем, зашёл на оф. сайт, скачал пак совместимый с моей версией ВиртуалБокса, установил в программе.
Теперь же она просто не видит устройство: в файловом менеджере флешка отображается, работает вполне корректно, загружался с неё на реальном ПК. 

Отображение в файловом менеджере:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ВиртуалБокс не видит устройство:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пока искал решение проблемы, наткнулся на статью, где говорилось, что в настройках системы для корректной загрузки с загрузочной USB с Windows необходимо включить в настройках системы EFI, что я и сделал:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Спустя несколько десятков минут поисков ответа, вопрос "В чём может заключаться ошибка и как её решить?" остался открытым. Подскажите, что делаю не такх, пожалуйста.

Comment: ищите, как пробросить usb устройство в конкретную машину, уже не помню, по моему машина должна быть включена, пробрасывать через главное меню Devices

Comment: @PavelGridin программа вообще не видит устройство, не то чтобы как загрузочное

Comment: так, что в главном меню `Устройства` ничего нет?

Comment: @PavelGridin дело в том, что устройства - выпадающий список типов устройств, которые могут быть подключены, а при выборе usb - перекидывает на ту же страницу настройки, что и заскринина в посте

Comment: ну, а нажатие кнопки с зелёным плюсом в фильтрах  не даёт список, что ли?

Comment: @PavelGridin почему-то скрин в посте этого не показал, но выводит что-то вроде "нет доступных устройств"

Comment: тогда не знаю, скорее всего, вас нет в какой-то группе

Comment: честно говоря, давно перешел с virtualbox на vmware именно, потому, что замучили проблемы с правами, ну и ещё у virtualbox тормознутые видеодрайвера

Comment: А что мешает просто цепануть iso как двд и просто поставить?